# Launching application from server creates Open File for lifetime of application

Tags: c#, .net, file, server

I launch a program located on one of my file servers. After launching the program it shows as an **Open file** in **Computer Management**.

Is there a way I can close this open file while my program runs so it doesn't show up in **Computer Management**?

My code is below. I'd be happy to take suggestions on improving my program, but I'm really just looking for a solution to stop all these **Open Files** from appearing.

Program.cs -- *starts the program, handles logic to launch my application*

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace IT_TaskbarApp
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string programName = "TEG System Helper";

        //Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(programName);

        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(programName).Length == 1)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Primary());
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName(programName))
            {
                if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id != p.Id)
                {
                    p.CloseMainWindow();
                    p.Close();
                    p.Kill();
                    p.Dispose();
                }
            }
            Main();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Primary.cs -- *creates an icon in the system icons which I can use to send notifications and easily access utilities within our organization*

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IT_TaskbarApp
{
public partial class Primary : Form
{
    private NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
    private ContextMenu contextMenu;
    private MenuItem[] menuItem = new MenuItem[8];
    private IContainer components;
    //private Boolean SendNotices = true;
    private DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    private DateTime currentTime;
    private Icon tegroupIcon = new Icon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("IT_TaskbarApp.Src.tegroup.ico"));
    
    private string prevNotification = "";
    private bool isRunning = true;
    private BackgroundWorker bgNotify = new BackgroundWorker();

    private const string programName = "TEG System Helper";

    public Primary()
    {
        this.FormClosing += Primary_FormClosing; //remove ghost icon in taskbar

        ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        BackColor = Color.Green;


        components = new Container();
        contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        for (int i = 0; i < menuItem.Length; i++)
        {
            menuItem[i] = new MenuItem();
            menuItem[i].Index = i;
            menuItem[i].Click += new EventHandler(LoadProcess);
        }

        menuItem[0].Text = programName;
        menuItem[1].Text = "Knowledge Base";
        menuItem[2].Text = "Policies";
        menuItem[3].Text = "Feedback";
        menuItem[4].Text = "Global Shop Search";
        menuItem[5].Text = "-";
        menuItem[6].Text = "Submit Ticket";
        menuItem[7].Text = "Send Email";

        //initialize contextMenu
        contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange(menuItem);



        // Create the NotifyIcon.
        notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon(components)
        {
            Icon = tegroupIcon,
            BalloonTipIcon = new ToolTipIcon(),
            ContextMenu = contextMenu, //the menu when right clicked
            Text = programName,
            Visible = true,
            BalloonTipTitle = programName,

        };

        notifyIcon.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(Icon_DoubleClick);

        InitializeComponent();

        bgNotify.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bgNotify.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgNotify.DoWork += NotifyUser;
        bgNotify.ProgressChanged += SendNotice;
        //bgNotify.RunWorkerCompleted += BgNotify_RunWorkerCompleted; //enable this to perform an action when the thread dies
        bgNotify.RunWorkerAsync();
        //Thread tNotify = new Thread();
    }

    #region SupportedFunctions

    private void NotifyUser(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter");
        while (isRunning)
        {
            currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            #region DisplayCurrentTime
            if (currentTime.Hour < 10 || currentTime.Minute < 10)
            {
                if (currentTime.Hour < 10)
                {
                    if (currentTime.Minute < 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("0{0}:0{1}", currentTime.Hour, currentTime.Minute);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("0{0}:{1}", currentTime.Hour, currentTime.Minute);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (currentTime.Minute < 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}:0{1}", currentTime.Hour, currentTime.Minute);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", currentTime.Hour, currentTime.Minute);
            }
            #endregion

            FileStream fs = new FileStream("\\\\te-admin\\public\\TaskbarNotices.txt", FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            string noticeText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            fs.Close();

            if (noticeText != "" && noticeText != prevNotification)
            {
                prevNotification = noticeText;
                bgNotify.ReportProgress(1);
            }
            else
            {
                bgNotify.ReportProgress(2);
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Inner Text: {0}  TOF: {1}", noticeText, noticeText != "");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }

    private void SendNotice(object Sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ProgressPercentage == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("notification sent");
            this.notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = prevNotification;
            this.notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1500);
        }
    }

    private void LoadProcess(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Sender is MenuItem)
        {
            MenuItem tempMenu = Sender as MenuItem;

            string ProgramTag = "http://";

            switch (tempMenu.Index)
            {
                case 0: //home page
                    ProgramTag += "teg";
                    break;
                case 1: //docviewer
                    ProgramTag += "teg/docViewer";
                    break;
                case 2: //policies
                    ProgramTag += "teg/Policies";
                    break;
                case 3: //feedback
                    ProgramTag += "teg/Feedback";
                    break;
                case 4: //inventory search
                    ProgramTag = "http://searchglobalshop/inventory/index.aspx";
                    break;
                case 6: //submit ticket
                    ProgramTag = "https://timberlandgroup.on.spiceworks.com/portal/tickets";
                    break;
                case 7: //send email
                    string sendto = "admin@tewinch.com";
                    string emailSubject = "Assistance Request";
                    string emailBody = "";
                    string mailto = string.Format("mailto:{0}?Subject={1}&Body={2}", sendto, emailSubject, emailBody);
                    ProgramTag = Uri.EscapeUriString(mailto);
                    break;
            }

            /*
             Try to launch the choice the user made with the default processing method.
             Should the default method fail we try to control how the process is run.
             We open internet explorer and then we show them what to do otherwise.
             */
            #region LaunchSelectedProcess
            try
            {
                if (ProgramTag != "" && ProgramTag != "http://")
                    Process.Start(ProgramTag);
            }
            catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ProgramTag.StartsWith("http://") || ProgramTag.StartsWith("https://"))
                        Process.Start("iexplore.exe", ProgramTag);
                }
                catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
                {
                    Process.Start("control.exe", "/name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms");

                    string message = "";
                    if (tempMenu.Index <= 6)
                    {
                        message = "You must have a default browser set\n\tClick [Set Default Program]\n";

                        if (Environment.OSVersion.ToString().Contains("NT 10.")) //windows 10
                        {
                            message += "\tUnder [Web Browser] Edge is currently set as default\n\tClick on Microsoft Edge\n\tSelect the browser you use";
                        }
                        else //windows 7 -- "NT 6.1")
                        {
                            message += "Select the browser you use\n\tClick [Set this program as default]";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Environment.OSVersion.ToString().Contains("NT 10.")) //windows 10
                        {
                            message += "Please setup a default email application";
                        }
                    }

                    message += "\n\nIf this issue persists please contact your Administrator.\nPhone: 519-537-6262\nEmail: admin@tewinch.com";
                    MessageBox.Show(message, "Application Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    //if ( == DialogResult.OK)

                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }

    private void Icon_DoubleClick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("http://teg");
    }
    #endregion


    #region BuiltFunctions
    private void Primary_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        notifyIcon.Icon = null;
        notifyIcon.Dispose();
        isRunning = false;
        Dispose(true);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Primary
        // 
        this.Icon = tegroupIcon;
        this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
        this.CausesValidation = false;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 23);
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.Enabled = false;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.Name = "Primary";
        this.Opacity = 0D;
        this.ShowIcon = false;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.SizeGripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide;
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Clean up any components being used.
        if (disposing)
            if (components != null)
                components.Dispose();

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Instead of cancelling the program on start up, I kill the other running instances of the program. The idea is that if any issues arise with the program I just launch another instance and resolve the issues. Right now not much can go wrong but we will be developing this program to complete many more tasks in the future.

The only area I can see which would keep a file open is when I pull an **Embedded Resource** tegroup.ico I was looking to see if I missed something while opening this, but I couldn't see a way to close the **ManifestResourceStream** after reading it in.

Any tips/suggestions would be wonderful but again, I really just want to know if there's a way I can close these **Open Files**

Example below

[Open File after app launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21DDO.png)

I might be trying to solve something which is a known result of using **Application.Run()** if this is the case then please suggest alternatives I can use. My other ideas would be loading the program into memory and launching it locally, using the .exe on the server as a starting point for this method though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Windows doesn't load an entire executable into ram.  It isn't just about files from the resource section of a PE file.  Portions of the exe are only loaded when referenced and even after loading everything there is to load, Windows will maintain an open file handle until the process closes.  Trying to close that handle yourself is a bad idea.

c/c++ allow a "SWAPFILE" flag to be specified that tells windows to put the whole thing into the page file but I don't know how you would do that with c# and I don't know if that would even stop windows from keeping the handle open anyways (I doubt it).

If this is truly important, iffin' I were your exe... I would:

1. Check a mutex for an existing running instance, exit if exist
2. Check where I was running from.
3. If running from temp, set a mutex that I am running and just run.
4. If not running from temp, copy myself to %temp%, start that copy, and exit.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great response.

Comment: You are welcome @CeaganP.  If you like it, I would appreciate you accepting this as your answer. :)

Comment: I am still looking into this as a solution. I should know within the next few hours whether this is.